# Vimtex and Xelatex

Tags: xetex

I tried for hours to use `vimtex` to compile a document that requires XeLaTeX. As the `vimtex` documentation says, the first line of my TeX document is `%! TEX program = xelatex`. However, I always get the following error:

> /usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty|43 error| Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"

So it look like PdfLaTeX is still used. Note that building a document that only requires PdfLaTeX work perfectly, and that the document I try to build with XeLaTeX is just a "Hello world" using a class that needs XeLaTeX and that compiles with `xelatex file.txt` command in a terminal.

Comment: can you try with: `%!TEX TS-program = xelatex`
and `%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode` on two first lines?

Comment: I know you "tried for hours", but have you actually put the line in the document and restarted vim afterwards? This is what I did wrong.

Comment: In a sufficiently new version, you don't need to restart Vim or press \lx. Just restart the compiler. https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/2168

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using `latexmk` to compile and you use `XeLaTeX` for the most of the time, I suggest change the defaut engine for your latexmk, just add one line to you `$HOME/.latexmkrc`

```
$pdflatex="xelatex %O %S";
```

Or you might want to keep pdflatex as your latexmk option. I suggest changing the choice of vimtex: add these lines to your `$HOME/.vimrc`

```
let g:vimtex_compiler_latexmk = { 
        \ 'executable' : 'latexmk',
        \ 'options' : [ 
        \   '-xelatex',
        \   '-file-line-error',
        \   '-synctex=1',
        \   '-interaction=nonstopmode',
        \ ],
        \}
```

`options` here stands for the options of `latexmk` when you use `\ll` to
compile in vim.

You can refer to the [Official Document](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/e323c55e9669c1adb205295b06ec4463bae5b637/doc/vimtex.txt#L795) to see more customizations for latexmk.

Comment: Note that method (1) might affect some other tools other than vim, as it "changes the default engine for latexmk". (2) **method 2 will not work** in the current version, because vimtex generates the command-line argument to specify the engine to use, and that overrides the argument provided. Instead use a directive line in the file itself (and restart the compiler), or see [plugin vimtex - xelatex as default latex engine - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/29301/26108) for setting the default setting.

Answer (score 3):

The exclamation point is in the wrong place. It should be this: `% !TEX program = xelatex` with the exclamation point right before the `TEX`. Then write the file, reload vimtex with `<leader>lx`, and recompile and see if that works.

Comment: It work as well like I wrote it. All I had to do was restarting Vim.